# Load more image/video hits on duckduckgo

Tags: duckduckgo

When searching images or videos on duckduckgo.com it displays just a few results compared to google. Is there any button or setting do make duckduckgo load more search results for images/videos?

Answer (score 1):

When you search through `Images` automatically shows more results when you scroll down:

> [image]

If more results are not loading automatically, there might be a button <kbd>Show More</kbd> for laoding more results for images.

You can toggle this settings from [DuckDuckGo Settings](https://duckduckgo.com/settings):

> [image]

Enabling `Auto-Load` will show you more results as you scroll-down and disabling it will show you <kbd>Show More</kbd> button.

For searching through `Videos`, you'll find <kbd>More Videos</kbd> button.